# Can I deduce $\lnot W, \lnot U$ from $\lnot W \land \lnot U$?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I have to prove this by contradiction for school :

$(X \lor Y) \implies M,\space M\implies (W \lor Z),\space Z \implies U, ¬(W\lor U)$ together, imply $¬Y $

I start by doing this :

$(X\lor Y) \implies M   \space $ Premise

$M\implies (W \lor Z)$  Premise

$Z\implies U \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space $  Premise

$¬(W \lor U) \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$  Premise

$¬(¬Y)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$  Contradiction of the conclusion

$ Y \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$  Double negation

$¬W \land ¬U\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$  De Morgan

I would like to know if I can do :
$¬W\land ¬U$
$¬W$
$¬U$

I would like to know if it's true so I can continue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What type of proposition are you trying to perform this proof on?

For instance, if this is proof by contradiction on a conditional statement the general form is $P\Rightarrow Q$ becomes $P\land\lnot Q$ from which you produce a contradiction $R\land\lnot R$. Where as if this is just a proposition $P$ then you derive your contradiction by assuming $\lnot P$ and producing a contradictory statement $R\land\lnot R$.

Comment: The contradiction of the conclusion is $\lnot Y$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to the $¬$ before the $Y$

Comment: Yes, from $\lnot W \land \lnot U$ you can derive $\lnot W$, and also $\lnot U$.  Sometimes this is called simplification (applied twice); some call it conjunction elimination (applied twice)..

Comment: Thank you a lot. I can finally be sure that I didn't lose an hour making a proof based on this. :D

Comment: @Hororo You are very welcome.

Comment: Also, a better word than "hypothesis" would be "premise." So that you have four premises, with a conclusion $\therefore \lnot Y$.

Comment: In French it's called hypothesis so I assumed that it was the same in English. Sorry if I caused any confusion

Comment: I was able to use a direct proof of the proposition, but it didn't include the third premise. If you have to use all four premises, then the proof is more cumbersome, and there is no place in the world for ugly logic or maths. In fact, if we go for the minimal numberof deductions to prove the result, premise 3 is unnecessary and can therefore be discarded. Try your hand at it; it's fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is:

1. (X∨Y)⟹M    (premise)
2. M⟹(W∨Z)    (premise)
3. Z⟹U        (premise)
4. ¬(W∨U)       (premise)
5. ¬W∧¬U       (de Morgan, 4)
6. ¬U          (simplification, 5)
7. ¬W          (simplification, 5)
8. ¬Z          (Modus Tollens, 3, 6)
9. ¬W∧¬Z       (conjuntion, 7, 8)
10. ¬(W∨Z)      (de Morgan, 9)
11. ¬M         (Modus Tollens, 2, 10)
12. ¬(X∨Y)     (Modus Tollens, 1, 11)
13. ¬X∧¬Y      (de Morgan, 12)
14. ¬Y         (simplification, 13)

And, if you wish, by **Contradiction**:

1. (X∨Y)⟹M    (premise)
2. M⟹(W∨Z)    (premise)
3. Z⟹U        (premise)
4. ¬(W∨U)       (premise)
5. Y            (sup. for contradiction)
6. ¬W∧¬U       (de Morgan, 4)
7. ¬U          (simplification, 6)
8. ¬W          (simplification, 6)
9. **¬Z**          (Modus Tollens, 3, 7)
10. X∨Y          (adition, 5)
11. M            (modus ponnens, 1, 10)
12. W∨Z          (modus ponnens, 2, 11)
13. **Z**            (disjunctive syllogism, 12, 8)
14. ¬Y           (by suppose 5, contradiction in 9, 13)

Comment: I forgot to write that I had to prove it by contradiction but you answered  my question with your proof. :)

Comment: Sorry! I just edit it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to prove $P \implies Q$, then:

A proof by contradiction would be $(P \land \lnot Q) \implies (R \land \lnot R)$.  We can't have both $R$ and $\lnot R$ true at the same time, hence the contradiction.

Related:  A proof by contrapositive would be $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$.